# Use a xsl:for-each over an xml to decide which label-value pairs are displayed?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm starting out XSLT I'm wondering if I can do this:

We're using this example http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog and modifying it a bit.

Paste the following into the XSLT area.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">


  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="country = 'USA'"> 
    <tr>
        <td>Title:</td> <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td>Artist</td> <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
        <td>Year:</td>  <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:when>

<xsl:otherwise>
    <tr>
        <td>Price:</td>     <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
        <td>Company:</td>   <td><xsl:value-of select="company"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What we've got here is a common XML source, but depending on one node of the XML elements (in this case the country), we want to display the data differently.

So far so good.

Now what we want to do, is use a XML structure to specify each of the Label to Node pairs that are to be displayed depending on the country. And then use a for-each loop to iterate over all the pairs and display them.

The rational for this, is that the format might be a bit more complicated than a simple LabelValue, and we don't to have to change all those manually later on.

This is what I tried.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="Details">
    <Details>
        <USA>
            <Pair><Node>title</Node><Label>Title:</Label></Pair>
            <Pair><Node>artist</Node><Label>Artist:</Label></Pair>
            <Pair><Node>year</Node><Label>Year:</Label></Pair>
    </USA>
    <Others>
            <Pair><Node>price</Node><Label>Price:</Label></Pair>
            <Pair><Node>company</Node><Label>Company:</Label></Pair>
    </Others>
</Details>
</xsl:variable>


  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="country = 'USA'"> 

    <xsl:for-each select = "$Details/Details/USA/Pair">
        <xsl:variable name="Node">
            <xsl:value-of select ="Node"/>
        </xsl:variable> 
        <tr><td><xsl:value-of select = "Label"/></td><td> <xsl:value-of select ="Node"/></td></tr>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:for-each select = "$Details/Details/Others/Pair">
        <xsl:variable name="Node">
            <xsl:value-of select ="Node"/>
        </xsl:variable> 
        <tr><td><xsl:value-of select = "Label"/></td><td> <xsl:value-of select ="Node"/></td></tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this doesn't work.

Can someone point me in the right direction for how I'd do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in XSLT 1.0, the **$Details** variable holds a 'result tree fragment', not a 'node-set', and XSLT needs it to be a node-set to access it in the way you require. To get around this in XSLT 1.0, you need to use an extension function to convert a result tree fragment into a node set. Which extension function you use depends on your current platform. For this example I am using Micorsoft, but the most common one outside of Microsoft is EXSLT. (See http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html)

By defining an extension function, you can then do this

```
<xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($Details)/Details/USA/Pair">
```

You still need a couple of tweaks to achieve your aim though. Within this loop you will be now positioned on the **Pair** element, but you need to reference back to the original **cd** in the outer loop. To do this you need to first define a variable to hold a reference to **cd** (This needs to go before the inner loop).

```
 <xsl:variable name="cd" select="." />
```

Then, in the inner loop, you can then do this to get the relevant field

```
<xsl:value-of select ="$cd/*[local-name() = current()/Node]"/>
```

It is worth mentioned, with your new code, you have the opportunity to reduce code duplication. You can ditch the **xsl:choose**, and just have one inner **xsl:for-each**

```
<xsl:for-each 
     select="$Details/*[local-name()=current()/country or local-name()='Others'][1]/Pair">
```

This will pick a matching country if it exists, otherwise it will use "Others"

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="Details">
    <Details>
        <USA>
            <Pair><Node>title</Node><Label>Title:</Label></Pair>
            <Pair><Node>artist</Node><Label>Artist:</Label></Pair>
            <Pair><Node>year</Node><Label>Year:</Label></Pair>
    </USA>
    <Others>
            <Pair><Node>price</Node><Label>Price:</Label></Pair>
            <Pair><Node>company</Node><Label>Company:</Label></Pair>
    </Others>
</Details>
</xsl:variable>

<html>
    <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
      <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Artist</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
          <xsl:variable name="cd" select="." />
          <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($Details)/Details/*[local-name()=current()/country or local-name()='Others'][1]/Pair">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select = "Label"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select ="$cd/*[local-name() = current()/Node]"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XSLT 2.0, things are different, **$Details** holds a 'sequence' and you would not need to use the extension function.

There is another way to achieve this, without an extension function, and that is to use the **document()** function to get XSTL to reference itself. Rather than just have a variable, you just include an XML fragment

```
  <my:Details>
    <Details>
     ...
    </Details>
  </my:Details>
```

Then you can declare a variable to reference it like so. Because you are referencing an input document directly, this is treating as a node-set.

```
 <xsl:variable name="Details" select="document('')/*/my:Details" />
```

Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="my" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
  <my:Details>
    <Details>
    <USA>
      <Pair>
        <Node>title</Node>
        <Label>Title:</Label>
      </Pair>
      <Pair>
        <Node>artist</Node>
        <Label>Artist:</Label>
      </Pair>
      <Pair>
        <Node>year</Node>
        <Label>Year:</Label>
      </Pair>
    </USA>
    <Others>
      <Pair>
        <Node>price</Node>
        <Label>Price:</Label>
      </Pair>
      <Pair>
        <Node>company</Node>
        <Label>Company:</Label>
      </Pair>
    </Others>
    </Details>
  </my:Details>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="Details" select="document('')/*/my:Details" />
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
            <xsl:variable name="cd" select="." />
            <xsl:for-each select = "$Details/Details/*[local-name()=current()/country or local-name()='Others'][1]/Pair">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select = "Label"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select ="$cd/*[local-name() = current()/Node]"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```